# Did the Vulgar Latin verb "toccare" exist?

Tags: verbs, spanish, vulgar-latin

According to the Royal Spanish Academy dictionary, the word *[tocar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Zw9dWu5)* 'touch' has its origin in the *toc toc* onomatopoeia. Something similar is registered in Etymonline for the English verb *[touch](https://www.etymonline.com/word/touch#etymonline_v_15414)*:

> from Old French *tochier* "to touch, hit, knock; mention, deal with" (11c., Modern French *toucher*), from Vulgar Latin **toccare* "to knock, strike" as a bell (source also of Spanish *tocar*, Italian *toccare*), perhaps of imitative origin.

This source refers to a hypotetical verb *toccare* that existed in Vulgar Latin, that supposedly was the origin of our modern words. But I see that the word *touch* is translated into Classical Latin as *[palpo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DP%3Aentry%20group%3D6%3Aentry%3Dpalpo1)* 'touch softly' (current Spanish: *palpar*) or *[tango](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=tango&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* 'touch' (origin of current Spanish *tacto* and *tañer*). So between these words and Old French *tochier* (11h century) or Spanish *tocar* (12th century) there must be a word that originated them.

So did the word *toccare* exist in Vulgar Latin as the origin of our current words for *touch*? If not, what could be transition from the Classical Latin words to the current ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your question implies, the * in ***toccare** means that the word is *unattested*, i.e., there is no direct written evidence that the verb actually existed.

This does not mean that there is a good argument against its existence: vulgar Latin/Proto-Romance was the language of (mostly) illiterate people. It doesn't mean either that there is no good argument *for* its existence. The very fact that there are dictionary entries mentioning it means that at least some experts consider it likely enough.

Digging a bit deeper on the evidence for the existence of *toccare, the story goes like this:

> (PIE<sup>1</sup>) `*dewk-` (*to draw, pull*) > (PIE) `*dukn-` > (Proto-Germanic) [`*tukkōną`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/tukk%C5%8Dn%C4%85) (*to pull, touch*) > (Frankish) [`*tukkōn/tokkōn*`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Frankish/tukk%C5%8Dn) (*to touch*) > (Latin) `*tocco/-are`

Part of the (extant, attested) evidence in which this *genealogy* is based is:

- (PIE) `*dewk-`: Latin *dux*, Spanish *conducir* (etc.)
- (Proto-Germanic) `*tukkōną`: English *tuck*, German *zucken*
- (Frankish) `*tukkōn/ *tokkōn`: Dutch *tokkelen*
- (Latin) well, you already mentioned it.

These reconstructions are based on the presence of the same root in one or several descendant languages. Moreover, the exact form of the unattested *ancestor* word is obtained by reversely applying the known sound changes that took place during the development of the descendant language.

The number of Romance languages with forms derived from *toccare is overwhelming, and all of them seem to point back at this particular form, hence the evidence for its existence is, IMHO, **difficult to argue against**.

---

<sup>1</sup> Proto Indo-European language, from which all Indo-European family languages are hypothesized to come.

Answer (score 4):

The [wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toccare#Italian) on the Italian verb *toccare* is somewhat more explicit, saying

> Probably from a Vulgar Latin root *toccare, of Germanic or onomatopoetic origin. Compare French toucher, Friulian tocjâ, Portuguese tocar, Romanian toca, Romansh tutgar, Sicilian tuccari, Sardinian toccai, Spanish tocar, Venetian tocar

The existence of descendants in such many languages and the application of sound laws in the French descendant make us really confident that the verb *toccare* goes back to Vulgar Latin, but the asterisk before it tells us that it is a reconstruction and not attested in the corpus of preserved Vulgar Latin. How it entered Vulgar Latin is an open question, as far as I can see.