# Could the vulgar verb "toccari" have existed in Vulgar Latin?

Tags: vulgar-latin, deponent-verbs, reflexive-pronoun

As a follow-up of the previous interesting question ([Did the Vulgar Latin verb "toccare" exist?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11099/did-the-vulgar-latin-verb-toccare-exist) ), could the vulgar Vulgar Latin verb *toccari* (in the sense of the deponent verb *masturbari*) have existed or should it have directly been created as reflexive like in Romance languages (e.g., *toccarsi* in Italian)? Just for an illustrious exemplification, cf. the famous dialogue between the priest (Don Balosa) and the boy (Titta) from Fellini's extraordinary Italian film "Amarcord":

Don Balosa: “Commetti atti impuri? Ti tocchi? Lo sai che San Luigi piange quando ti tocchi?”

Titta: “Ma perché, tu non ti tocchi? Ma come si fa a non toccarsi quando vedi la tabaccaia con tótta quella ròba lì davanti, o la professoressa di matematica, che sembra un leone? Come si fa a non toccarsi quando ti guarda in quel modo? E allora come faccio a dirgli di no quando la Volpina mi ha chiesto di gonfiargli la bicicletta? Io non sapevo che si davano i baci così. Lei lo sapeva? Con tutta la lingua che gira...”

Don Balosa: “Sono io che faccio le domande!”

---

Exactly, “sono io che faccio le domande!”: Could the vulgar Vulgar Latin verb "toccari" have existed  or  should it have directly been created as reflexive like in Romance languages (e.g., *toccarsi* in Italian)? More generally, could anyone provide me with references on the progressive absence of deponent verbs from Vulgar Latin?